# How to update a translatable model using DRF and hvad

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-hvad

I'm using Django Rest Framework with hvad to handle translations.
implementing CRUD operations I realize that if I have a object with ID 1 in 'en' language, if I try to update the object but using the 'fr' code, the object isn't founded
but for example in Admin panel, I can update/create the translation.

For example, updating the object with the language code who's the object was created
[image: update success]

And now trying to update the same object but the other language code
[image: update failed]